# IPUMS Population Counts

Tags: r, census

I'm trying just to get the total population from the 1% sample from Data I got through IPUMS. I'm doing a by-person analysis so i was going to use the personweight variable.

According to this [site](https://medium.com/pew-research-center-decoded/using-tidyverse-tools-with-pew-research-center-survey-data-in-r-bdfe61de0909), I would just need to add the weights to get the population counts. That almost seemed too simple to be true. I compared it to the overall population and the differences were just too steep. (never expected them to match completely but being off by a few million seemed wrong)

```
weight <- a_1850_1880_pop %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(count = sum(PERWT))
```

[image]

What would I need to run in order to get a weighted total?

Answer (score 0):

Your method (adding the weights) is right. The reason for the discrepancy is likely that published population counts include both free and enslaved persons, whereas the IPUMS USA 1850 and 1860 1% samples include only free persons (see sample descriptions [here](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/sampdesc.shtml#us1850a)).